# How do I use LINQ to return the first item from each set of Grouped data (In VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

Given a simple DTO (AccountExpiry) with properties of 'AccountNo' and 'ExpiryDate'
and a List of same created thus:

```
    New AccountExpiry(123, New Date(2012, 4, 1))
    New AccountExpiry(123, New Date(2012, 4, 2))
    New AccountExpiry(123, New Date(2012, 4, 3))

    New AccountExpiry(124, New Date(2012, 4, 2))
    New AccountExpiry(124, New Date(2012, 4, 3))
    New AccountExpiry(124, New Date(2012, 4, 4))
```

How do I use LINQ to retrieve the most recent entry per account

I have a feeling this will involve GroupBy and FirstOrDefault.

It seems like...

```
From Item In Source Group By Item.AccountNo Into Group
```

...should return all of the data grouped appropriately, but It is unclear how I might apply .FirstOrDefault to each group.

I'm sure this is a simple question for anyone who has done this before, but it is very unclear to me at present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be something like this:

First group the items, then get the most recent date per group, and select the items with those most recent dates.

```
Module Module1

    Class AccountExpiry
        Public Property AccountNo As Int32
        Public Property ExpiryDate As DateTime
        Public Sub New(accountNo As Int32, expiryDate As DateTime)
            Me.AccountNo = accountNo
            Me.ExpiryDate = expiryDate
        End Sub
    End Class

    Sub Main()

        Dim list = {New AccountExpiry(123, New Date(2012, 4, 1)),
                    New AccountExpiry(123, New Date(2012, 4, 2)),
                    New AccountExpiry(123, New Date(2012, 4, 3)),
                    New AccountExpiry(124, New Date(2012, 4, 2)),
                    New AccountExpiry(124, New Date(2012, 4, 3)),
                    New AccountExpiry(124, New Date(2012, 4, 4))}

        Dim grouped = From ae In list
                      Group ae By ae.AccountNo Into Group

        Dim newest = From g In grouped
                     Let maxDate = g.Group.Max(Function(e) e.ExpiryDate)
                     Select g.Group.Single(Function(e) e.ExpiryDate = maxDate)

        For Each x In newest
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} : {1}", x.AccountNo, x.ExpiryDate))
        Next

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Beware that `Single()` will fail if `ExpiryDate` is not unique within the `AccountNo`-group. You could e.g. also use `First()`, but it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks very much, that'll do nicely :)